# Check box not being changed as I would expect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a simple widget that allows the user to select either the check box OR the whole div to change its value. I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".inputCheck", function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".outter").trigger("click");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".outter", function(event) {
    console.log("inside");
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var $checkBox = $(this).find("input");
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
    $checkBox.prop("checked", !$checkBox.prop("checked"));

    if ($checkBox.prop("checked"))
      $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.outter {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.outter:hover,
.inputCheck:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outter">
    <input class="inputCheck" type="checkbox">
    <div>This is a test</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works as normal when the div is selected I.e. Checkbox changing values and a new class 'selected' being added to the .outter class. When the checkbox is selected I try to stop all defaults and propagation and then trigger the same code as selecting the div to change the class value. However the check box stays the same. Can someone please tell me why this isn't working and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Your selector is wrong, the class for input element is `inputCheck` not  `inputCheckBox`

Comment: oopps yes wait i'll change that . I still think there's a problem though

Comment: Yes it still doesn't work sorry I knocked this this example after I couldn't getting it working in other code...

Comment: Please add it in code snippet.

Comment: I know it is a pain, I had to do this a lot. If you can make a jsfiddle out of it I can fix it for you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wq56t9bo/1/

Comment: When you say "value", what do you mean? `value` attribute? text content? `.class`?

Comment: I still don't understand what you want... but at least you got your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to stop propagation or anything. You can just check if the click was on the input or not, then change the input checked status like following. The click on the input will automatically be propagated to the parent div. You can check the click origin using `event.target` and make necessary actions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".outter").click(function(event) {
    console.log('clicked');
    var $checkBox = $(this).find("input");
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
    if (!$(event.target).is($checkBox)) {
      $checkBox.prop("checked", !$checkBox.prop("checked"));
    }
    if ($checkBox.prop("checked"))
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.outter {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.outter:hover,
.inputCheck:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outter">
  <input class="inputCheck" type="checkbox" />
  <div id="testIt">This is a test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rejith, that's great. Why was the original not working do you know?

Comment: @xenophon the problem with the original code was that, when you click on the input that gets marked as checked, then the outer click is triggered. There the function toggles the input's checked property again. That means change on the input will happen twice.

Comment: But why wouldn't the preventDefault and stopPropagation functions stop this?

Comment: @xenophon the stopPropagation stops the event from propagating. But you have the code `$(this).closest(".outter").trigger("click");`, which will excecute the code below.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".inputCheck", function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).closest(".outter").trigger("click");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".outter", function(event) {
    console.log("inside");
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var $checkBox = $(this).find("input");
   
    

    if ($checkBox.prop("checked"))
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    else
       $(this).removeClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.outter {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.outter:hover,
.inputCheck:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outter">
    <input class="inputCheck" type="checkbox">
    <div>This is a test</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```